# Alternative Window Manager for Windows 10 OS

Tags: windows-10, window-manager

Is there any software that would completely strip out the UI from windows and replace it with another window manager similar to Mate, Gnome or KDE? I've taken registry hacks, classic shell, and other UI customizations to there limit.

Comment: hmm.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows  Cygwin/Mate...